# Containerisation setup on Cloud

Tags: containers, cloud

I am new to containerisation and starting to use on one of the clouds (AWS or Azure or GCP). While reading the difference between VM and containers, I understood that we should use either VM or Containers for app deployment.
So if I setup my own container environment on cloud (instead of using AWS/Azure Container service), I eventually end up creating containers on top of VMs. This defeats the whole purpose of containerisation!

Is my understanding correct? Below is the image of VM, Container and Container on VM.

[VMs, Containers and 'Containers on VM'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMjrT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is pretty correct. However such cloud providers usually also install their container setup on a vm.

A VM has a higher overhead than a container but also gives you better security. (It's more easy to break out of a container than of a real virtualization platform.)

Because of security issues with containers providers usually setup their container environment on a vm and only provision containers of the same customer on this vm.